# Оптимизация проиндексированного списка

Tags: java, список, структуры-данных

**Попалась мне занятная организация списка.**
Кроме `List<Object>` делают `Map<Object, Integer>`. И если нужно получить объект по индексу, то обращаются в List, а если узнать индекс объекта то лезут в Map.
Вот и заинтересовался, а действительно ли это быстрее или трата оперативки попусту?
P.S. Первое точно помню: ArrayList, а вот второе не помню. (Вечером допишу)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Map` и `List` — это интерфейсы, поэтому на ваш вопрос нельзя строго ответить, не зная, какие за ними стоят реализации. Если вы имеете в виду `HashMap` и `ArrayList`, то да, с большой вероятностью `HashMap.get(obj)` будет быстрее, чем аналогичная `ArrayList.indexOf(obj)` даже если у вас 10-20 элементов. Если вам часто нужна операция `indexOf`, то такой подход оправдан. Хотя стоит задаться вопросом, зачем вам в принципе такая операция. Возможно, стоит вообще пересмотреть подход к организации данных.